# Changing text on button in muliple item (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to using react.I have a series of data witch there is a button in every item and by clicking it the text of a special div must be changed, but in my issue by clicking the  button of one item , the text of the div in all items will be changed.I want when i click the button , the text of that div which there is in that item be changed.Thank in advance

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props, context){
super(props, context);
this.state = {
data: [],
};
    $.ajax({
    url:"/json.bc",
    type:"get",
    success:(result)=>{
    this.setState({data: eval(result)});
    }
    })
    }
   renderFlight(){
   return this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.total -    b.total).map((item,i)=>{
  return(
  <div class="item"> <div class="btn" onClick={((e) => this.rueldep(e, item))}>click</div>
  <div  class="text">{this.state.txt}</div>
  </div>
 )})}
 rueldep= (e, item) => {
  var Text= item.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description
   if (typeof desc === 'string'){
    return desc
     } else {
    this.setState({
        txt: Text
     });      
    }
    }; 

  render(){
    return(
   <div>{this.renderFlight()}</div>
    )}}
   ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Comment: Do u have unique id per object in data array?

Comment: yes , but id is an object and i can not to use it. i tried to user "i" in (item,i).

Comment: Let me know what you have in this.state.data?

Comment: [{'_id': {'value': 'eydGYXJlU291cmNlQ29kZSc6ICczMzMyMzUzNjM5NjMzNjM1MzEzNTY0MzIzNDY2MzI2MjM5NjUzMjM5NjIzMDYzNjM2MjYyMzY2MzM4MzczODMzMjYzNjMzMjYzMzMyMzgzMjMxMzMzODM4JywgJ3Byb3ZpZGVyJzogeydwcm92aWRlcl9pZCc6ICczJywgJ2RtbmlkJzogMzk4MS4wfSwgJ2ZhcmV0eXBlJzogNH0=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '3', 'dmnid': '3981-0'}, 'fareType': 4}]

Comment: this is one of the  id of my items  it is an object

Comment: I have updated my answer please give a try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using index from map

Initialize one number variable in state

```
  this.state = {
     data: [],
      id: 0
  };
```

In rueldep handler function set index + 1 to id state variable like below

```
    rueldep= (e, item, index) => {
      var s = item.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description
       if (typeof desc === 'string'){
         return desc
       } else {
            this.setState({
                txt: 'clicked',
                id: index+1
            });      
        }
      };
```

Now in renderFlight method compare selected id and id from data if both matches display text to particular div something like below. Also don’t forget to add unique key to parent jsx element when you render in loop

```
  renderFlight(){
     return this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.total -    b.total).map((item,i)=>{
     return(
        <div key={"Key-"+i} class="item"> <div class="btn" onClick={e => this.rueldep(e, item, i)}>click</div>
       <div  class="text">{(this.state.id == i +1) ?this.state.txt : null}</div>
    </div>
     )})}
```

Comment: i can not use id from data. it is an object

Comment: I am not using id. Please carefully read my updated answer once

Comment: Thanks Hemadri Dasari.

Comment: I am sorry Hemadri Dasari , but there is a problem. i do not know why when i click the button in  item1 and show the text in div class="text" and then  i click the button in item2 the text of div class="text"  of item1 will be empty???

Comment: Yes Clicked will be displayed for only matching one. When second one clicked the first one text will disappear

Comment: an other problem is that for all the items shows the text of first item!!

Comment: so, what should i do? i want when ever click on the botton the text be shown and otehers wont be disappeared?